# WebGL readPixels returns flipped y axis

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have no idea why but the image that I read from canvas gets flipped on y axis.

The ultimate goal is the read a portion of WebGL canvas and extract it as JPG/PNG.

Workflow is the following:

- gl.readPixels
- create 2D canvas
- load Uint8Array pixels to 2D canvas as imageData
- get 2D canvas as blob
- create object URL
- use it as image src

Here's my code: https://jsitor.com/acM-2WTzd

I'm really sorry about the length (almost 300) but it's WebGL, there's so much boilerplate and setup.

---

I've tried to debug it for several hours and I have no idea (granted it could be the shader, I'm quite new at that).

If you have any additional question, please feel free to ask!

Comment: Hi, Were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike [`context.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData), [`gl.readPixels()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/readPixels) reads pixel data starting from the bottom-left corner, not from the top-left corner. You can apply a transformation on `tempCanvas` and draw it onto itself after putting the image data like this:

```js
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
// add the following
context.translate(0, cropHeight);
context.scale(1, -1);
context.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can manually rearrange the pixel data before returning it from your `getPixels()` function:

```js
function getPixels(x, y, width, height) {
  const length = width * height * 4;
  const row = width * 4;
  const end = (height - 1) * row;
  const arr = new Uint8Array(length);
  const pixels = new Uint8Array(length);

  if (draw) draw();
  gl.readPixels(x, y, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, arr);

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i += row) {
    pixels.set(arr.subarray(i, i + row), end - i);
  }

  return pixels;
}
```